# Custom validation for a Rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tre models

```
class ChallengeItem < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :photos
end

class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :challenge_item
  has_many :votes
end

class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :photo
  validate :vote_per_foto

  private

  def vote_per_foto
    if self.class.exists?(photo_id: photo_id, voter_string: voter_string)
      errors.add :vote, 'already voted'
    end
  end
end
```

Basically for every group of photos (ChallengeItem) user can vote only one photo.
Every vote has a fingerprint attribute, called `voter_string`

I write a custom validation, but with this validation I accept just one vote for photo. I need one vote for every group of photos...

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Look to the [#uniqueness](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) validator with the scope option to limit one associated record. You can do something like

```
validates :voter_string, uniqueness: { scope: { :photo_id } }
```

to get just one `Vote` with a given `voter_string` per given `photo_id`.

Comment: is not what I need. I don't need one vote for photo_id, I need one vote for challenge_item.photos

Comment: I misunderstood. If it's a 1 `Vote` per `ChallengeItem` why don't you have a direct `belongs_to` relation between the two models?

Comment: Because people must vote the best photo for every challenge item. The vote belongs to the photo... but they can vote just one photo

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the vote exists for any photos in the `challenge_item`:

```
def vote_per_foto
  if self.class.exists?(photo_id: photo.challenge_item.photos.select(:id), voter_string: voter_string)
    errors.add :vote, 'already voted'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is setup an indirect association:

```
class ChallengeItem < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :photos
  has_many :votes, through: :photos
end

class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :challenge_item
  has_many :votes
end

class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :photo
  has_one :challenge_item, through: :photo
  validate :one_vote_per_challenge_item

  def one_vote_per_challenge_item
    if challenge_item.votes.exists?(voter_string: voter_string)
      errors.add :base, 'already voted'
    end
  end
end
```

This will let you access `challenge_item` from a photo instance and Rails will handle joining for you.

Comment: However since there is no database index backing the uniqueness it can be prone to race conditions.